# How to calculate the size of heap, file, variable or any element from memory adress?

Tags: files, ram

I'm currently trying to get the size of the heap of a process and I got some confusions.

In proc/PID/maps I got:

```
009df000-00a01000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

I know that if I subtract the final memory address to the initial I got the total size in bytes, but I got confusions in if I should divide it by 1000 or 1024 to convert it in kilobytes.

Google says 1000 bytes are 1 kilobyte, but some other pages says 1024 is 1 kilobyte. So, when should I use each conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check memory usage of process which exits immediately](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459665/check-memory-usage-of-process-which-exits-immediately)